# Where is ECS Task Stopped Reason now?

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, amazon-ecs

I am using the AWS interface to configure my services on ECS. Before the interface change, I used to be able to access a screen that would allow me to see why the task had failed (like in the example below), that interface could be accessed from the ECS service events by clicking on the taskid. Does anyone know how to get the task stopped reason data with the new interface?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see essentially the same message if you do the following steps:

1. Select your service from your ECS cluster:

[image]

2. Go to `Configuration and tasks` tab:

[image]

3. Scroll down and select a task. You would want to chose one which was stopped by the failing deployment:

[image]

4. You should have the `Stopped reason` message:

[image]

Comment: You know if there is a way to see what happend with the failed tasks of the Deployment tab? the event is not very clarifying and there isnt a single task in "Configuration and tasks" tab :/ Im probably messing with placement constraints or task memory/cpu size

Comment: My problem was that I was creating half of the resources (task definition) with the new interface and the other half (service) with the old interface. The new interface apparently uses a different, non-retrocompatible backend, so the task never started. I fixed it by just using the old interface for everything.